# Broken DAG : ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'airflow.providers.snowflake'

Tags: airflow

Hi I have setup my environment for Airflow run. I want to run the DAG whcih connects to Snowflake. I have installed below necessary packages from cloud shell.

```
pip3 install snowflake-connector-python==2.4.5
pip3 install snowflake-sqlalchemy==1.2.4
pip3 install apache-airflow-providers-snowflake==2.3.0
pip3 install apache-airflow-providers-common-sql
```

I have established snowflake connection in Airflow.

```
Now while executing the DAG i am getting this error since long time:
```

```
    Broken DAG: [/home/airflow/gcs/dags/snowflake_connect_mine.py] Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/home/airflow/gcs/dags/snowflake_connect_mine.py", line 6, in <module>
    from airflow.contrib.hooks.snowflake_hook import SnowflakeHook
      File "/opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/contrib/hooks/snowflake_hook.py", line 23, in <module>
    from airflow.providers.snowflake.hooks.snowflake import SnowflakeHook  # noqa
    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'airflow.providers.snowflake'
```

Please help me to resolve this issue.

Regards
Sachin Mittal
9560315720

Comment: What was your soution?